# Swipe to go to next item in recyclerview

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

am new to android, i have a recycler view in my activity, when i click on an item a new activity opens with details related to that specified item. My need is that when I swipe on the opened activity i need to go to next page of next recycler view item

Answer (score 2):

Here's how I would solve this. For my example, I'll consider an email application, where my `RecyclerView` shows each email's sender and subject, and my "details" view shows the contents of each email (and allows swiping between emails).

First, I would create only a single `Activity`. This activity would host my list of data (my emails). This activity's layout would include a `FrameLayout` that I'd use to host `Fragment`s.

My first `Fragment` would have a `RecyclerView` (and its `Adapter` etc). Whenever I clicked on an email, I'd send that email's `position` up to my `Activity`, which would then use a `FragmentTransaction` to `replace()` my list `Fragment` with my details `Fragment`.

This details `Fragment` would have a `ViewPager` (and its `Adapter` etc). Each page in the `ViewPager` would show the body of an email. Because I'm using `ViewPager`, I get automatic swiping between emails.

Answer (score 0):

what you can do pass data array to intent and position then you can setup next position for right swap send specific data similarly previous position for left swap.